# How to Switch Audio Output through i3?

Tags: linux, pulseaudio, i3, tiling-wm

I've tried an assortment of Google results already, but haven't found anything that works or simple.

How would you cycle or switch through audio outputs on Pulseaudio through an i3 keyboard shortcut?